# 錐体の頂点の真上からボールを落とした際に、ボールが刺さらないようにしたいです

Tags: unity3d

Unityで頂点の真上からボールを落下させた場合、ProBuilderで作成したConeに刺さってしまいます。
SphereのPhysic Materialの`bounciness`を設定した場合もバウンドすることなくConeに刺さってしまいます。
頂点から少しずれる場合、Coneの斜面に沿ってボールは転がっていきます。
現実では頂点に落下したボールは跳ねる、もしくは軌道がそれて転がっていくと思うのですが、Unity上でその動作を実装するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

蛇足かもしれませんが、ConeをSphereに変更した場合、ボールは落下後数回バウンドし転がっていきました。

[image: 落下時の状態]